# Parse a string of multipart data

Tags: python, multipartform-data, aws-api-gateway

I have a string (base64 decoded here) that looks like this:

```
----------------------------212550847697339237761929
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="preferred_name"; filename="file1.rtf"
Content-Type: application/rtf

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf830
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 testing123FILE1}
----------------------------212550847697339237761929
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to_process"; filename="file2.rtf"
Content-Type: application/rtf

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf830
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 testing123FILE212341234}
----------------------------212550847697339237761929--
```

I generate this on a simple webpage that uploads a couple files to a AWS Lambda script through a PUT request with the API Gateway. It should be noted that what I get from the API Gateway is a Base64 string that I then decode into the string above.

The string above is the data that my Lambda script receives from the API gateway. **What I would like to do is parse this string in order to retrieve the data contained within with Python 2.7.** I've experimented with the `cgi` class and using the `cgi.parse_multipart()` method, however, I cannot find a way to convert a string to the required arguments. Any tips?

Comment: This data is a [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) file format. Take a look at [Pyth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyth/).

Comment: I understand the format of the data, however, how do I extract it from the multipart message?

Comment: It seems to be multi files, instead of multipart. Example: `filename="file1.rtf"` and `filename="file2.rtf"`. Maybe, trying to access one of this files, before uploading, to map the structure of file.

Comment: I also need this ! [NodeJS has busboy for this](https://develandoo.com/blog/nodejs/parsing-multipart-body-aws-lambda-function-serverless), but I'm looking for how to do this on Python just like you (although I'm using 3.6)...

Comment: *I've experimented with the cgi class and using the cgi.parse_multipart() method*, could you please include that attempt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Comment**:  is it robust and spec compliant?

As long as your Data follow this Preconditions:

- The **First** line is the **boundary**
- The Following Header is terminated with a **empty** Line
- Each Message Part is terminated with the **boundary**

---

> **Comment**: What if the content is binary like a JPEG stream?

This is likly to break as there are **String** Methodes used and reading the content is using `.readline()` which depends on **New Line**.
Therefore to `decode` from BASE64 and then `unpack` Multipart are the **wrong** Approach!

---

> **Comment**: If there's a version reusing a common library

If you are able to provide your Data as Standard **[MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)** Message you can use the following:

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_string(mimeHeader+data)
print('is_multipart:{}'.format(msg.is_multipart()))

for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue

    filename = part.get_filename()
    payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
    print('{} filename:{}\n{}'.format(part.get_content_type(), filename, payload))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> is_multipart:True
> application/rtf filename:file1.rtf
> b'{\rtf1\x07nsi\x07nsicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf830\n{\x0conttbl\x0c0\x0cswiss\x0ccharset0'... (omitted for brevity)
> application/rtf filename:file2.rtf
> b'{\rtf1\x07nsi\x07nsicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf830\n{\x0conttbl\x0c0\x0cswiss\x0ccharset0'... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

---

> **Question**: Parse a string of multipart data

Pure Python Solution, for instance:

```
import re, io
with io.StringIO(data) as fh:
    parts = []
    part_line = []
    part_fname = None
    new_part = None
    robj = re.compile('.+filename=\"(.+)\"')

    while True:
        line = fh.readline()
        if not line: break

        if not new_part:
            new_part = line[:-1]

        if line.startswith(new_part):
            if part_line:
                parts.append({'filename':part_fname, 'content':''.join(part_line)})
                part_line = []

            while line and line != '\n':
                _match = robj.match(line)
                if _match: part_fname = _match.groups()[0]
                line = fh.readline()
        else:
            part_line.append(line)

for part in parts:
    print(part)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> {'filename': 'file1.rtf', 'content': '{\rtf1\x07nsi\x07nsicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf830\n... (omitted for brevity)
> {'filename': 'file2.rtf', 'content': '{\rtf1\x07nsi\x07nsicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf830\n... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I appreciate this, but is it robust and spec compliant? What if the content is binary like a JPEG stream? If there's a version reusing a common library, I'd love to know it.

Comment: Excellent answer! I found a different solution (didn't post it as it did not answer the question, AWS Lambda Stuff), but fascinating nonetheless!

Comment: @Tanishqdubey can you show me where you found a solution to this? I'm in a similar situation regarding a raw form-data string on AWS lambda

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with an API, it is better to use json formatted data.
You can use the requests module to send PUT request to the API and it will return you the response object from which you can retrieve the json data easily by using the method **response.json()**

Comment: I am aware of this, but multipart is both standard and necessary for transmitting binary files over HTTP(s). It's possible to workaround it by encoding in Base64 and wrapping inside JSON but then it becomes nonstandard and much less efficient, probably less robust too.